# Is it possible to share/create Spark session in UDF?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

Is it possible to somehow use spark session inside the UDF function? I will have to ingest the data from child tables as well on the basis of referenced table. It's looking like this:

```
def select(entity):
    query = f"SELECT * FROM `{database.value}`.`{table.value}`  WHERE id='{entity}'"
    records = spark.sql(query)
    # store records on S3 in CSVformat, filename table_name.csv
    return records
    
ingestion = F.udf(select, ArrayType(StringType()))

try:
    glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    query = f"SELECT * FROM `{database}`.`{entity_table}`"        
    entities = spark.sql(query)
    # store records on S3 in CSV format, filename entities.csv
    
    tables_with_relations = ["entity.some_child_table", "another_child_table"]
    for child_table in tables_with_relations:
        table = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(child_table)
        response = entities.withColumn("response", ingestion("id"))
        response.show()
            
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

In this case I am getting some pickling error and if I try by creating/accessing another spark session as following:

```
def select(entity):
    query = f"SELECT * FROM `{database.value}`.`{table.value}` WHERE id='{entity}'"
    glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    records = spark.sql(query)
    return records
```

Then I got this error:

```
Exception: SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.
```

I am not experienced in Spark, therefore if it is not something for which UDF has been introduced, then I am fine with nested `for` loops, otherwise can somebody recommend how to achieve this either by using UDF or any other approach?

Comment: simple answer - you can't. you could, however, (potentially) try to use RDD transformations

Comment: what do you want to achieve - describe the final result

Comment: @AlexOtt if query is successful in select(), then I will just store the results on S3 in CSV format. That's it. Means first storing parent table's records and then child tables records in separate CSVs.

Comment: send sparksession in udf is against the concept of sparksession. sparksession should be only on drive while udf is shared from driver to all executors.

Comment: If I convert the spark dataframe (entities) to pandas dataframe, and use `entities.apply(lambda entity: select(entity))`, then I am able to use spark session inside select()! Could you please help me understand why it is possible in pandas df, not in spark sql df?